# How to change target directories structure of nuget package

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

While installing Nuget package like bootstap using visual studio 2017, for example, nuget manager installing the css files of bootstrap package in "~/Content/" directory while i prefer it to be located in "~/Content/css".

[image]

i know that i can move the files manually and to change the reference manually but then, i will need to do it again every time i am updating the package using visual studio nuget package manager.

i am wondering, if there is an option to tell every package where to install the relevant files so it will be remembered for later updates.

Comment: This is not supported by NuGet. The location of the files is determined by the NuGet package itself.

Comment: using NuGet to acquire javascript/"web client" assets is discouraged, consider using npm instead (VS may eventually gain support for a new meta-package manager based on https://github.com/aspnet/LibraryInstaller)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i am wondering, if there is an option to tell every package where to install the relevant files so it will be remembered for later updates.

I am afraid **there is no such option** to tell every package where to install the relevant files. According to the [conventions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BmCI.png) for `.nuspec` file:

[image]

The convention for `content` is:

> *Think of the content folder as the root of the target application that ultimately consumes the package. To have the package add an image
>   in the application's /images folder, place it in the package's
>   content/images folder.*

Just like Matt comment, "The location of the files is determined by **the NuGet package itself**", so there is no such option to tell every package where to install the relevant files.